# Service Fabric and TCP connections

Tags: tcp, azure-service-fabric

We have developed a TeamViewer-like service where clients connect via SSL to our centralized servers. Other clients can connect to the server as well and we can setup a tunnel through our service to allow peer-to-peer connectivity without NAT or firewall issues.

This works fine with Azure Cloud Services, but we would like to move away from Azure Cloud Services. Service Fabric seems to be the way to go, because it supports ARM and also allows much fine-grained services and make updating parts of the system much more easy.

I know that microservices in Service Fabric can be stateful, but all examples use persistent data as state. In my situation the TCP connection is also part of the state. Is it possible to use TCP with service fabric?

The TCP endpoint should be kept alive on the same instance (for several days), so this makes the entire service fabric model much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can have users connect to your services over any protocol you want. Your service sounds very stateful to me in the same way that user session state is stateful - you want users to return to the same place where their data is. In your case, that "data" is a TCP connection. But there's no guarantee a TCP endpoint will be kept alive for days in *any* system - machines fail, software crashes, OSes get patched, etc. You need to be prepared for the connection to break so you can quickly re-establish it. Service Fabric stateful services are great for this. Failover of a stateful service to another machine is extremely fast (milliseconds). Of course, you can't actually replicate a live connection, but you sure can replicate all the metadata you need to re-establish a connection if it breaks.

Comment: We are resilient when a TCP connection is terminated (the client simply reconnects to a possible different instance). In the meantime, results are buffered (for a limited period of time). I am still in doubt whether to use Service Fabric. A docker swarm might be just as useful for our service and I guess Docker support for Windows in Azure will be there in the near future.